# Can't install openssl-devel for Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, linux, cryptography

when i install the cryptography,there have some errors,for the platform is :

```
[root@RHanible ~]# python -V
Python 2.7.11
[root@RHanible ~]# rpm -qa openssl
openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64
[root@RHanible ~]# rpm -qa openssl-devel
openssl-devel-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64
[root@RHanible ~]# rpm -qa python-devel
python-devel-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64
[root@RHanible ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
```

the errors is following:

```
already up-to-date
building '_openssl' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/python/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2078: warning: function declaration isn?. a prototype
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2079: warning: function declaration isn?. a prototype
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2080: warning: function declaration isn?. a prototype
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2105: warning: function declaration isn?. a prototype
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2163: warning: function declaration isn?. a prototype
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c: In function ?.cffi_const_CMS_DEBUG_DECRYPT?.
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:8193: error: ?.MS_DEBUG_DECRYPT?.undeclared (first use in this function)
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:8193: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:8193: error: for each function it appears in.)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following steps and it worked for me on my virtual environment. First, I installed python development headers and libevent headers.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev 

sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

then, I used documentation 
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux

Comment: sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel ,yes,i do this ,but can't solve this,,this is openssh problem?but i have install the package